# Prolog Goal Query Returns False

Tags: prolog

I'm a high school student studying Prolog and am getting an error on a goal.

I have the following facts:

```
character(jim).
character(jenny).
character_type(jim, prince).
charcter_type(jenny, princess).
skill(fly).
skill(invisibility).
has_skill(jim, fly).
has_skill(jenny_invisibility).
pet(jim, horse).
pet(jenny, bird).
animal(horse).
animal(bird).
```

I would like to get all the pets of characters who are princesses. I am trying:

```
pet(character_type(_, princess), X).
```

Without successful results. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anything starting with lower case letter in Prolog is atomic and not a variable. So `pet(character_type(_, princess), X).` fails because neither of the two `pet` facts you have will unify with that term. They won't unify because `jim` does not match `character_type(_, princess)` and `jenny` does not match `character_type(_, princess)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog, arguments to predicates and functions can only be terms. A term is combinations of variables, constants, and functions. Terms cannot contain predicates.The Predicates are names for functions that are true or false.The functions are something that return non-Boolean values.

The argument passed in pet predicate i.e character_type is a predicate, thus cannot be written as pet(character_type(_, princess), X).

Instead writing the query as
**character_type(X,princess), pet(X,Y).** will give you the desired result. 
X= jenny
Y = bird.

Comment: *A term is combinations of variables, constants, and functions.*. Prolog does not have "functions". Predicates are not functions. Everything in Prolog is a term, and a predicate is a set of terms of the form, `:-(head, body)` typically written as, `head :- body`, where `head` and `body` are also term forms. Predicates succeed or fail and do not "return" values.

Answer (score 1):

you can not use prolog predicate like C-Function

```
    character_type(_, princess)
```

returns nothing.

I think this is what you intend to do.

```
    character_type(C, princess),pet(C, X).
```